# Slack Chatbot Integration with Blueprism

Tags: chatbot, slack, slack-api, blueprism, rpa

I have a Blueprism process and have a Slack account as well. So is there any way to use slack bot along with blue prism? if it is so how we can implement the middle layer between slack and blue prism? Can i use slack API to this integration? Please help me out with a strategy.

Actually I need to create a slack chat bot which can communicate with the blue prism process and get the result to the user in chat. Upto now i have implemented a slack chatbot using node.js server. So i can call a webservice by it whenever user request the process run. In Blueprism i was able to find out that web service can trigger a process. But still i couldnt find how api call can trigger the process in blueprism side

Comment: I'm not familiar with slack, but I'm pretty sure BP can communicate with an API via http requests. The implementation itself however can vary a lot so, I believe the question right now is too broad; there could potentially be several largely differing solutions (meeting your untold requirements or not).

Comment: Hi Jerry thanks for the comment. Ya BP can communicate thorugh http requests but need to find our slack is providing this facility

Comment: It depends what exactly you want to do with Slack. Most of Slack API's work with standard HTTP requests. The Real Time Messaging API works with Websockets. However, your question is a bit too broad to give any specific answer. So I would advise to study the [Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/) and start with something simple like sending a message.

Comment: Actually I need to create a slack chat bot which can communicate with the blue prism process and get the result to the user in chat. Upto now i have implemented a slack chatbot using node.js server. So i can call a webservice by it whenever user request the process run. In Blueprism i was able to find out that web service can trigger a process. But still i couldnt find how api call can trigger the process in blueprism side

Comment: If you need your pre-existing Slack bot to communicate with Blue Prism, you might want to look at the "[Resources - Consuming an Exposed Web Service](https://portal.blueprism.com/documents/resources-consuming-exposed-blue-prism-web-service)" on the Documents tab of the Blue Prism portal. It explains in detail how to expose and implement a process/object as a SOAP web service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with BluePrism, but all workspaces in Slack can be integrated with the API.

As Jerry as said, it's a pretty broad question, so the best I can really do right now is point you to [this getting started guide](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps). I'd have a read over that and if you've a more detailed question I'd post again and me or others will follow up.

Happy building!

Comment: Hi Colm, Actually i dont have the access to that document at the moment. But as i experienced chatbot can call a webservie from slack side. Then the webservie can be catched on blueprism and it triggers the process. Right now i am thinking to run a batch file to run the blueprism process and finding a way to run the batch file from a web servie. Then i can directly call that service from slack and run the batch file then it will run the blueprism command. Please give ur ideas as well.

Comment: Hey Dinesh, I honestly don't have any experience with BluePrism so I couldn't say. Hitting an endpoint from Slack is pretty trivial, it's just a matter of configuring it in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to trigger BluePrism processes via a web service call.
Here the information from the official BluePrism documentation:
Link to the Web Services documentation for e liberate details:

[Web Services documentation](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/documents/v6.3%20User%20Guide%20-%20Web%20Services.pdf)

[Guide to Dynamic Process Execution](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/documents/Guide%20to%20Dynamic%20Process%20Execution.pdf)

> Starting a Process using Web Services
>   Web Services call can be used to start a Process directly, or indirectly utilizing the Master Process technique described below. 
>   This section focuses on a direct start, meaning that the actual work will be performed by the Process (or Object) exposed as a Web Service. Web Services Guide6 specifies that the call needs to be made to a
>   particular Resource ( http://[machinename]:/ws/). The Web Services Guide also examines different scenarios of exposing and consuming Objects and Processes and effects on License utilization.
>   Resource availability and execution time should be considered when deciding to expose a Web Service. If the Resource is busy, it may not be able to service the request, and a large Process may take time to return a result to the caller. As such it is recommended to expose only short, rapid Processes (or Objects), such as ones that simply store input data in a Work Queue or return results from a Work Queue.

You'll need to create an account on https://portal.blueprism.com to read to the documentation.
Something which is advice able anyways when you're using Blue Prism ;).

Hopefully this helps you further.